# Docker ppa package for Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: docker

Does someone knows if it exists some ppa packages source for the newest Ubuntu version 19.10 i had problem with that when i upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10 i didn't work?

Comment: You have to write support request to repository owners asking package for 19.10.

Comment: Do you know any site where i can find any info about who is repository owners for Docker?

Comment: Just to be clear - do you mean `docker.io` [package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=docker.io) or you mean `docker-ce` package from Docker.com (they really do not have [*eoan*](https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/) yet)?

Comment: I thinking about docker -ce!

Comment: Norbert can add this as an solution so that i can mark this question as solved? if they dosen't have add this as an package to EOAN Ubuntu 19.10 it could explain this problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The Docker repository currently have packages for 20.04 (*focal*), so you can follow official guide or use commands below:

```
sudo apt install curl
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable"
sudo apt install docker-ce
```

Comment: Thank you Norbert for the temporary solution:)!

Comment: same song at every release -_-;   You'd think they'd make it some sort of priority.

Comment: Hahaha thanks everybody why is my question a good one?

Comment: Does anyone know if there's a downside to installing from docker.io? I'm new to this and don't know about the difference

Answer (score 1):

There is no Docker Package (yet) for Ubuntu 19.10 Eoan Ermine, as issued here: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/832. The Package of the previous Ubuntu 19.04 Disco Dingo will work for most users.

To solve this, avoid polluting `/etc/apt/source.list`.

**Option 1**: add a .list file to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` by:

```
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list'
```

**Option 2**:

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list
```

add (if you have docker installed alread before, change there **eoan** to **disco** as:)

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable
```

Other solutions like a manual install you could find here: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/833

Answer (score 1):

if you're not sure which lsb release that docker has and you're host are compatible with, you could check `/etc/debian_version` and then check the link `https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu`, it'll list all releases that docker supports
for example on my host, the `lsb_release -cs` outputs `bionic` but when `cat cat /etc/debian_version`
it says

```
buster/sid
```

so I chuse `buster` one from the docker releases

Comment: This is about Ubuntu, not Debian. And the OP was about a release that is now EOL, so not sure this really adds anything.