# unable to download updates failed to refresh cache the repository download.docker.com does not exist

Tags: docker, 19.10

I wanted to play some songs when I got to see this
[image: unable to download updates]

I have a few flv files and I wanted to play them.
I am using Ubuntu in a Vmware environment here is when I see all the problems. This one was upgraded from 19.04 to 19.10
my /etc/apt/sources.list file looks like this

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 19.04 _Disco Dingo_ - Release amd64 (20190416)]/ disco main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates main
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ disco-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security main
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu eoan-backports universe multiverse main
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

https://pastebin.com/CiUTguW7

any other file if I should paste let me know
**edit 1**
in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ there are 2 files

```
docker.list  linuxuprising-ubuntu-java-eoan.list
```

and docker.list file has following

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
```

and  linuxuprising-ubuntu-java-eoan.list file has

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu eoan main
# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxuprising/java/ubuntu eoan main
```

Comment: Look in the *directory* `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` for the docker source that you need to delete.

Comment: while trying to play an audio/video file your "player" tries to download the codecs for it (guess gstreamer)... It looks like that an additional ppa in your source.lst or in sources.list.d folder references an invalid ppa.
The previous comment is right. Check your sources.
Concerning your secondary problem: The "totem" video player packaged with ubuntu/debian does not work really well, install vlc instead, which contains all major (unfree & free) codecs.

Comment: @user535733 I added lines in question below section edit1, I don't have much idea what to now I had installed hadoop on this system so docker might have installed from sources.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker ppa package for Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185882/docker-ppa-package-for-ubuntu-19-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's review...

The error message says:

```
...The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/eoan Release does not have a Release file.'
```

You have a source file, `/etc/apt/apt.sources.d/dockerlist` that contains the following entry:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
```

Note the resemblance: Now you know which source is triggering that message. And you know which file that source is in.

---

Next, let's try that source URL in a web browser:  https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/

It brings up a web page. If you look on that page under the `dists/` link, you will see that Eoan (19.10) is not listed. There are NO packages for your release (Eoan/19.10) at that source.

As you have discovered, adding a source that has no packages for your release of Ubuntu will trigger warning messages.

How to eliminate the warning messages:

1. Delete the source.  Use `sudo rm` on that source file.
2. Then run `sudo apt update` to refresh your package database. Always perform an `update` when you add, delete, or change any package source.

Comment: Hello @user535733 I unistalled docker and the same error message appears. How can fix it? Docker is not necessary to download updates right?

Comment: @GennaroArguzzi If it's *the same error message*, then either your sources didn't look like the original question or you didn't follow the instructions in this answer. If it's *a different error message*, then you have a different problem.