# Error: 'deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable' invalid

Tags: apt, package-management, docker

I've added `deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable` to my sources.list, and then ran `sudo apt update`, which returns:

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stabl
e' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stab
le' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable'
 (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component '
stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stabl
e' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stabl
e' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/dep11/icons-128x128.tar' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'stable/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' doesn't have the component 'stable' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Has anyone experienced the same? I couldn't find the reason for it, or how to fix it.

Comment: According to https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/833 Docker is not working for 19.10 yet.  They are claiming that you can use the Disco (19.04) to make it work.

Comment: I agree with the error message, knowing nothing about docker sorry, but opening https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu in a browser I don't see a 'stable'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker ppa package for Ubuntu 19.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185882/docker-ppa-package-for-ubuntu-19-10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker doesn't exist for 19.10 yet, and no eoan repository exists yet, so you will need to use the 19.04 version.

In your deb statement, change the Ubuntu version like so:

Change:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu eoan stable
```

To:

```
deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable
```

Comment: I'd suggest stating that "Docker doesn't exist for 19.10 yet, so you will need to use the 19.04 version." as well to indicate *why* they should change it (so it's a more complete answer)

Comment: @ThomasWard Done. Thanks!